# R — Assign value to vector based on first episode

Tags: r, vector, sequence

So I have a sequence dataset that looks like this

```
  id epnum clockst
1  1     1       0
2  1     2       1
3  1     3       2
4  2     1       4
5  2     2       5
6  2     3       6
7  3     1       4
8  3     2       5
9  3     3       6
```

What I want is to create a vector of `clockst` based on `epnum == 1`.

So, I want basically this

```
  id epnum clockst ep_start
1  1     1       0        0
2  1     2       1        0
3  1     3       2        0
4  2     1       4        4
5  2     2       5        4
6  2     3       6        4
7  3     1       4        4
8  3     2       5        4
9  3     3       6        4
```

However, I struggle to do so.

I came up with this, but it doesn't fully work.

```
dt$ep_start = ifelse(dt$epnum == 1 & dt$clockst == 0, 0, 
    ifelse(dt$epnum == 1 & dt$clockst == 4, 4, -9))
```

Any idea?

## Data

```
dt = structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), epnum = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
clockst = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("0", 
"1", "2", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
"epnum", "clockst"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking about. I don't understand what is `ep_start` is.

Comment: doesn't deserve a vote `down` though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `library(data.table)` as follows

```
T <- data.table(T)
T[, ep_start := .SD[1]$clockst, by = "id"]
```

This gives:

```
   id epnum clockst ep_start
1:  1     1       0        0
2:  1     2       1        0
3:  1     3       2        0
4:  2     1       4        4
5:  2     2       5        4
6:  2     3       6        4
7:  3     1       4        4
8:  3     2       5        4
9:  3     3       6        4
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using tidyverse:

First check the condition `epnum == 1` and if `TRUE`, use `clockst` value if not  `NA`. Then just fill `NA` with previous values.

Since `clockst` is a factor one needs to convert it to numeric while keeping the same values so `as.numeric(as.character(` needs to be used.

```
library(tidyverse)
dt %>%
  mutate(ep_start = ifelse(epnum == 1, as.numeric(as.character(clockst)), NA)) %>%
  fill(ep_start, .direction = "down")
#output:
  id epnum clockst ep_start
1  1     1       0        0
2  1     2       1        0
3  1     3       2        0
4  2     1       4        4
5  2     2       5        4
6  2     3       6        4
7  3     1       4        4
8  3     2       5        4
9  3     3       6        4
```

Here is a quick comparison of the available answers. I chose to use a 90 k row data set:

```
df <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), times = 10000),] #where df = dt

dt <- data.table(df)

library(microbenchmark)
bench <- microbenchmark(SunBee = dt[, ep_start := .SD[1]$clockst, by = "id"],
                        missuse = df %>%
                          mutate(ep_start = ifelse(epnum == 1, as.numeric(as.character(clockst)), NA)) %>%
                          fill(ep_start, .direction = "down"),
                        d.b. = df$clockst[rep(which(df$epnum == 1), rle(cumsum(df$epnum == 1))$lengths)],
                        www = df %>%
                          arrange(id, epnum) %>%
                          group_by(id) %>%
                          mutate(ep_start = first(clockst)) %>%
                          ungroup())

plot(bench)
```

[image]

with a 900 k row data set:

[image]

oh man I really need to learn DT.

Comment: @giacomo added a benchmark of the available solutions.

Comment: thanks that is great! well now that I am dealing with large database, `data.table` is indispensable! `dplyr` is just too slow, despite its beautiful synthax!

Answer (score 2):

Another `tidyverse` solution. `arrange` is not required if you are certain that the rows are in the right order.

```
library(dplyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  arrange(id, epnum) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(ep_start = first(clockst)) %>%
  ungroup()
dt2
# # A tibble: 9 x 4
#   id     epnum  clockst ep_start
#   <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>  <fctr>  
# 1 1      1      0       0       
# 2 1      2      1       0       
# 3 1      3      2       0       
# 4 2      1      4       4       
# 5 2      2      5       4       
# 6 2      3      6       4       
# 7 3      1      4       4       
# 8 3      2      5       4       
# 9 3      3      6       4
```

Comment: interesting thank you, I didn't know about the `function first`

Comment: Another assumption of my answer is that all the id group has 1 in epnum. If that is not true, other people’s answer are better.

Comment: yes actually here this is the case, but thanks for raising this point. One issue is that I am working with a huge dataset so `data.table` is more efficient here. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
dt$ep_start = dt$clockst[rep(which(dt$epnum == 1), rle(cumsum(dt$epnum == 1))$lengths)]
dt
#  id epnum clockst ep_start
#1  1     1       0        0
#2  1     2       1        0
#3  1     3       2        0
#4  2     1       4        4
#5  2     2       5        4
#6  2     3       6        4
#7  3     1       4        4
#8  3     2       5        4
#9  3     3       6        4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `match`

```
clock = dt[dt$epnum == 1, ]
dt$ep_start = clock$clockst[match(dt$id, clock$id)]
```